# React bulma components import is not working

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, bulma

I have created the react app using `CRA (CREATE-REACT-APP)`. I have installed `node-sass` and renamed `App.css` to `App.scss` and updated its import in `App.js`. Now in my `App.js`, I am just trying to print some text inside a section.

[image: I am getting this error:]

[This is the link the repo, I am talking about. For your reference](https://github.com/couds/react-bulma-components#readme)

`node -v` v12.11.1 and `npm -v` 6.11.3

`App.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.scss';
import Section from 'react-bulma-components/lib/components/section';

function App() {
  return (
    <Section>
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="title">
          Hello World
      </h1>
        <p class="subtitle">
          My first website with <strong>Bulma</strong>!
      </p>
      </div>
    </Section>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`App.scss`

```
@import 'react-bulma-components/src/index.sass';
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "just-trying",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "react": "^16.11.0",
    "react-bulma-components": "^3.1.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.11.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Which node version are you? Its node version issue

Comment: node -v
v12.11.1 and 
npm -v
6.11.3

Comment: Try Downgrading node to v11.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of downgrading the version of node, I have uninstalled react-bulma-components and instead just installed bulma via npa like npm i bulma.. and that works fine.